# How to add prefix (or scope) to all logging through instance of class?

Tags: c#, logging

I would like to have all logging initiated from an instance of a class A prefixed by an id like this:

```
A123: Calling B1
A123: Executing B1
A123: Calling B2
A123: Executing B2

A234: Calling B1
A234: Executing B1
A234: Calling B2
A234: Executing B2
```

I made an attempt using BeginScope, but it will not work since BeginScope is not scoped to class A and it's dependencies.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace LoggingTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AddConsole()
                    .AddSimpleConsole(options => options.IncludeScopes = true);
            });
            ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();

            A a = new A(123, logger);
            a.A1();
            a.A2();

            a = new A(234, logger);
            a.A1();
            a.A2();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        private ILogger _logger;
        private int _id;
        private B _b;

        public A(int id, ILogger logger)
        {
            _id = id;
            _logger = logger;
            _logger.BeginScope("A{}", _id);
            _b = new B(logger);
        }

        public void A1()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Calling B1");
            _b.B1();
        }

        public void A2()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Calling B2");
            _b.B2();
        }

    }

    public class B
    {
        ILogger _logger;

        public B(ILogger logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void B1()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Executing B1");
        }

        public void B2()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Executing B2");
        }
    }
}

info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123
      Calling B1
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123
      Executing B1
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123
      Calling B2
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123
      Executing B2
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123 => A234
      Calling B1
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123 => A234
      Executing B1
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123 => A234
      Calling B2
info: LoggingTest.Program[0]
      => A123 => A234
      Executing B2
```

Is it possible to achive this using natural ILogger constructs?

Comment: Which version of of .NET are you using? Maybe use `ILogger<A>` then preface message with `Id`?

Comment: I'm using .net 6. Not sure how that would work. How does B know what to log?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line gives an idea on how to use `ILogger` it also states :"Starting with .NET 6, logging services no longer register the ILogger type. When using a logger, specify the generic-type alternative ILogger<TCategoryName> or register the ILogger with dependency injection (DI).". You don't appear to be using DI so maybe use `ILogger<A>` in `A` and `ILogger<B>` in `B`

Comment: @ChrisBD If I use ILogger<B> in class B (which is used from A). How will B be able to log the A prefix?

Comment: Isn't the idea that each class performs its own logging? If you want them on the same line then you'll probably need to place the logging in class A to show that it is calling class B

Comment: No, that would be super trivial. The idea is that an orchestrator class can decide the logging context to be used for all sub-operations.

Comment: Could you use dependency injection to inject the ILogger instance?

Comment: How would using dependency injection make this any easier? Class A and clas B will then use independent loggers and how would class B know about the A prefix that shuld be added when logging from B?